# NSLayoutConstraint and spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 `UILabel` in a `UIView`:

```
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[headerViewLabel]-[headerViewVersionLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerViewVersionLabel, headerViewLabel)]];
```

I'm having trouble getting the `headerViewLabel` to take up more space then it is:

[image]

I want the "New" label to be as small as possible aka `sizeToFit` and let the "New Event" stretch out farther.

How can I do this?

SOLVED:

Thanks to Matt, I added increased the "New"'s priorityHugging:

```
[headerViewVersionLabel setContentHuggingPriority:251 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

and works like a charm:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've omitted an important piece of the puzzle: you are not going to get the New Event to stretch unless you pin its left side, which you have neglected to do.

Second, the labels are both already trying (at a low level of priority) to size themselves to fit their text. It is impossible for them to do that *and* for them to be pinned at both ends and to one another.

The solution is to nudge the horizontal hugging priority of one of them, to be greater than the other. In your case, the New label needs a higher horizontal hugging priority; one point added will do. Keep the New Event label at its default horizontal hugging priority (probably 250) and set the New label to one point higher (probably 251).

Comment: Ugh, yep. I do have a `UIImageView` that is pinned to the left side and attached to the "new Event" label.

Comment: Ok, I set the `setContentHuggingPriority` and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the justification of the new label to be right justified it will do what you want.  At least it works for me setting it up in interface builder.